# Store value of "if any(" search

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to store the value of word, is there a way to do this?

```
if any(word in currentFile for word in otherFile):
```

Comment: Let's say `currentFile` contains the words 'hello', 'world', 'banana' and `otherFile` contains 'banana', 'world', 'apple'. What should be the result? 'world' or 'banana' or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `any` if you want the words themselves:

```
words = [word for word in otherFile if word in currentFile]
```

Then you can truth-test directly (since an empty list is falsy):

```
if words:
    # do stuff
```

And also access the words that matched:

```
print words
```

**EDIT**: If you only want the *first* matching word, you can do that too:

```
word = next((word for word in otherFile if word in currentFile), None)
if word:
    # do stuff with word
```

Comment: Just note that `if word in currentFile` is going to be very slow, you should read `currentFile` into a `set` and use that instead.

Comment: This words great, my only issue now is the the formatting of word

it looks like this ['pineapple'], I need it to just be pineapple

Comment: @NeonLights86: Then just print the element(s) you want. You know how to work with lists, don't you?

Comment: Yeah, I'm new at this but figured it out. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Just a little follow-up:
You should consider what is an input to `any()` function here. Input is a generator. So let's break it down:

- `word in currentFile` is a boolean expression - output value is True or False
- `for word in otherFile` performs an iteration over `otherFile`

So the output of `any()` argument would be in fact generator of boolean values. You can check it by simply executing `[word in currentFile for word in otherFile]`. Note that brackets means that a list would be created, with all values computed at once. Generator works functionally the same (if what you do is a single loop over all values), but are better memory-wise. The point is - what you feed to `any()` is a list of booleans. It has no knowledge about actual words - therefore it cannot possibly output one.

No. You'll have to write explicit loop:

```
def find_first(currentFile, otherFile)
    for word in currentFile:
        if word in otherFile:
            return word
```

If no match is found, function would implicitly return `None` which may be handled by a caller outside of `find_first()` function.

Comment: if i understand correctly, OP wants to use `if any` and stores the value of `word`

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to store this value directly from `any`. I'd recommend a for-loop

```
for word in otherFile:
    if word in currentFile:
        break
else:
    word = None
if word is not None:
    print word, "was found in the current file"
```

Note that this will store only the first relevant value of `word`. If you would like all relevant values of `word`, then this should do it:

```
words = [word for word in otherFile if word in currentFile]
for word in words:
    print word, "was found in the current file"
```

Comment: have you tested your post yet?  `[word if word in currentFile for word in otherFile]` is wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can get the *first* word from `otherFile` that is also in `currentFile` by [dropping](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) all words from `otherFile` that are *not* in `currentFile` and then taking the [next](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#next) one:

```
from itertools import dropwhile
word = next(dropwhile(lambda word: word not in currentFile, otherfile))
```

If there is no such word, this raises `StopIteration`.

---

You can get *all* words from `otherFile` that are also in `currentFile` by using a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
words = [word for word in otherFile if word in currentFile]
```

Or by using a [set intersection](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets):

```
words = list(set(otherFile) & set(currentFile))
```

Or by using the [`filter` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter):

```
words = filter(lambda word: word in currentFile, otherFile)
```